# MongoDB corrupts binary data! (express.js , multer)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

**What am I trying to do?**: So, basically I will be uploading a .zip file and it will get saved in MongoDB and then users can open the store and download that files!

**Steps:**

1. Firstly, I am uploading the file using Multer in express.js!

```js
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.memoryStorage()
}).fields([
    { name: 'fileupload'},
    { name: 'logo' },
    { name: 'screenshots' }
])
```

So I am saving the files into memory and then adding them into the database. This includes:- (a) array of images, (b) One single image file (c) A .zip file (This is where the problem is!)

2. Storing it in database:-

```js
return await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
        try {
            const result = await new pluginSchema({
                name ,
                desc ,
                price ,
                category ,
                file ,
                logo ,
                images ,
                reviews,
                coupon
            }).save()

            pluginCache[result._id] = result // Caching the file (IMPORTANT)
            return result
        } finally {
            mongoose.connection.close()
        }
    })
```

Once added, I am storing the plugin(.zip file) into a cache variable. And I will be using that variable to get the "result" instead of fetching from the database multiple times!

**The problem**: Okay, so now , once I try to go to the product page and click download, it begins the download of the file. This time, the plugin is fetched from the cache variable i.e. the cached result is returned and that is being downloaded. This is how I download it,

```js
res.set({
            "Content-Type": plugin.file.mimetype,
            "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=${plugin.file.originalname}`
        })
        res.send(plugin.file.buffer)
```

And the file downloads perfectly fine and nothing is corrupted!

BUT!

When, I restart the server, all the variables are cleared and the cache variable gets cleared, so now the plugin is fetched from the database. And once it fetches from the database and when I download that file, I am getting .zip file corrupted.

**Important Stuff**:
Console.logging req.files(multer stores the files here):-

```js
{
  fieldname: 'fileupload',
  originalname: 'example.jar',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/x-zip-compressed',
  buffer: <Buffer >, // CMD Doesn't display entire buffer data, but I have checked and this exists!
  size: 0
}
```

And the data is saved into MongoDB in this way,
[MongoDB][1]

And whenever I fetch the files directly from MongoDB, the files gets corrupted but when I upload the files and cache them and use the cached variables, everything works fine!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEPpt.png

**Some stuff which I dont think matters**: Downloading the corrupted file(fetching and downloading from MongoDB) makes the file size 14KB(instead of 11KB) and that .zip file cant be unzipped! Also, the images are getting saved perfectly fine, but why is the .zip getting corrupted!

Comment: I have found a work around to do it, creating a folder, and put all the files in it and then zip the folder and then upload it.